# How to sort different struct models in array in swift?

Tags: swift

1. I have unsortedArray[AnyObject] array. I have added three struct models (Notification model , YouCard Model , Welcome Model) in it . All these three models containg "time_stamp" parameter in string format.
   Now i am unable to sort the the models on the basis of time_stamp.
2. I am not comfortable with swift functions. I have tried one solution but its not working

   [image]

Comment: You cannot compare items of different type using `!`. The closure can be called with the items in reverse order, the first can be `NotificationCard` and the second `YouCard`. Why don't you create a common protocol for cards and use it instead of `AnyObject`?

Comment: What's the problem you're having?  You need to show a lot more info.

Comment: I have three struct models . Each models having timestamp paramter. I want to sort these models on the basis of time stamp.

Comment: I have no clue how to create protocol for this models.please elaborate more..

Comment: Any link you can provide so that i can refer that link

Answer (score 1):

That's a classical case to use a protocol, avoid as much as possible arrays declared as `[AnyObject]` or even `[Any]`.

- Create the protocol, all structs which adopt that protocol must implement `timestamp`

  ```
  protocol TimeStampable {
      var timestamp : TimeInterval { get }
  }
  ```
- Create the three classes

  ```
  struct NotificationCard : TimeStampable {
      var timestamp : TimeInterval = 34837465928
  }

  struct YouCard : TimeStampable {
      var timestamp : TimeInterval = 67837465928
  }

  struct WelcomeCard : TimeStampable {
      var timestamp : TimeInterval = 92837465928
  }
  ```
- Rather than unspecified `[AnyObject]` declare the array as `[TimeStampable]`

  ```
  let unsortedArray : [TimeStampable] = [YouCard(), WelcomeCard(), NotificationCard()]
  ```
- Now you can sort the array

  ```
  let res = unsortedArray.sorted{ $0.timestamp < $1.timestamp }
  ```

If you have to use other common members or functions add them to the protocol declaration and implement them in the structs and/or use a protocol extension.

Comment: i will try this solution . thanks and get back to you if any problem occurs

Comment: **What** is not working? My code stand-alone does work.

Comment: may be i have implement in the wrong way.. Your approach is good.Thanks for your help. It is more comfortable for me if we sort it with help of array.