# Swift - display two different arrays of structs in a table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Let's say I have an array of each struct `a` & `b` and I'm currently using a table view to display array `a`. Both structs contain amongst other things a date.

My intention is to additionally display the array of struct `b` in the same table view and order the table by the dates of both arrays - don't know whether that's possible.

Further more I'd like upcoming dates to be not directly in the view, but only when the user scrolls up - so to say on top of the table.

**TimelineViewController:**

```
extension TimelineViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return addDataArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let rowData = addDataArray[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TimelineCell") as! TimelineCell

        cell.setDrivenKm(drivenKm: rowData.driven)
        cell.setDate(date: rowData.date)
        cell.setConsumedL(consumedL: rowData.consumedL)
        cell.setPricePerLiter(pricePerLiter: rowData.pricePerLiter)

        return cell
    }

}
```

**Struct `a`:**

```
var addDataArray: [addDataStruct] = []

func createStructArray() {
        ...

        let addData: addDataStruct = addDataStruct(date: Date(), ...)
        addDataArray.append(addData)
    }

struct addDataStruct: Codable {
    var ...: Int
    var date: Date
    var ...: Double
    var ...: Double
    var ...: Int
}
```

**Struct `b`:**

```
var notStructArray: [not] = []

func createStructArray() {
        ...
        let notificationData: not = not(date: datePicker.date, ...)
        notStructArray.append(notificationData)
        notStructArray.sort(by: { $0.date < $1.date })
    }

struct not: Codable {
    var ...: String
    var ...: String
    var date: Date
    var ...: Int
    var ...: Int
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what your goal is. Do you want to show all of the rows from struct A followed by all of the rows from struct B or do you want to mix the two arrays together, all sorted by date and then shows all the rows in order regardless of which struct is came from? In other words, do you want "A A A A B B B" or do you want "A B B A B A A", for example?

Comment: @rmaddy I want the to be mixed together and then sorted by the date.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428042/displaying-two-different-types-of-cells-after-date and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47598436/how-to-sort-different-struct-models-in-array-in-swift?r=SearchResults&s=1|93.0874 for good starting points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `protocol` with common property with `Date` type and add it in both structs. In `ViewController` add an array which merges both array and sorts by date.

Use that array in `tableView` data source methods.

```
protocol CommonData {
    var date: Date { get }
}
struct A: CommonData, Codable {
    var date: Date
    var x: String
}
struct B: CommonData, Codable {
    var date: Date
    var y: String
}
class TimelineViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var arr1: [A] = []
    var arr2: [B] = []
    var totalArr: [CommonData] {
        return (arr1 as [CommonData]) + (arr2 as [CommonData]).sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date })
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        arr1.append(A(date: Date(), x: "x"))
        if let yesterDay = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: noon) {
            arr2.append(B(date: yesterDay, y: "y"))
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return totalArr.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
            ?? UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
        print(totalArr[indexPath.row].date.description)
        if let data = totalArr[indexPath.row] as? A {
            print(data.x)
        } else if let data = totalArr[indexPath.row] as? B {
            print(data.y)
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```